# Show only some bar labels for matplotlib bar chart

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a bar chart with a lot of columns (around 100).  I want to show only some of the bar labels (they are ordered in such a way that this is a perfectly reasonable way to present the data).  Is there a simple way to do this, say show every 3rd or 5th label?  I know I can manually pull together the list, but I figure there's likely an elegant option.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.random.rand(100)
groupings = np.arange(0,100)
x_pos = [i for i, _ in enumerate(groupings)]
plt.bar(x_pos,data)
plt.xticks(x_pos,groupings)
```

Comment: `plt.xticks(x_pos[::3], groupings[::3])`?

Comment: Thanks @DavidG I knew there had to be an elegant solution.  If you make this an answer I'll accept it.  (this probably should have been obvious, but I'm not a good python coder)